# Password reminder in Windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, passwords

I have windows 7 at work and I have some network drives connected which require to login to access them. After a few months the password used to connect to the network drives expires, but windows 7 does not present me the possibility to change this password so how can I do in order to windows 7 to let me change the password for a new one? I mean, when password expires, windows says to me it has been expired but it does not offer me the possibility to change the password for a new one.

Thanks.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete; Select "Change a Password"?

Comment: This happened to a user in the office. Ctl-Alt-Del didn't change the network login password.